# Image does not load always in react native image component from network

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Images from network does not load always, sometimes it do and sometimes it does not.Below is my render method.

```
render() {
let {title, image, text, publisher, id, date} = this.props.webDetail;
let dateString = Moment(date).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY');
let metaDetail = `${publisher}\n${dateString}`;

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.publisher}>{metaDetail}</Text>
              <Image
                 style={styles.image}
                 source={{ uri: image }} indicator={Progress}
              />
               <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
              {this.renderButton.call(this) }
         </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
}
```

And image is passed in feed object. When parent's touch event is invoked, feed object is passed as props in child.

```
 renderContent(feed) {
    let dateString = Moment(feed.date).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY');
    let metaDetail = `${feed.publisher}\n${dateString}`;

    return (
        <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{feed.title}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.publisher}>{metaDetail}</Text>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                onPress={this.onPress.bind(this, feed) }>
                <Image style={styles.image} key={feed.image} source={{ uri: `${feed.image}?version=outside` }} indicator={Progress} />
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            <Text numberOfLines={7} style={styles.text}>{feed.description}</Text>
            <Share rank={feed.rank}/>
        </ScrollView>

    );
}
```

Comment: share code which is used to set webDetail

Comment: webDetail is fine, i always get valid image url, only thing is it renders image sometime, & sometimes it don't

Comment: are you sure that image url is always taken before render process is started.

Comment: Please check the above edit. feed object ( where image is present as one of the key/value ). Render content is parent function

Answer (score 0):

Could be a fresco caching issue, try making the url unique each time by adding a random number to the image url: `imageUrl + ?"+new Date().getTime()`.

There are various issues with fresco and images, like this one for example:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8677

Comment: let me try this solution